# How can I sort numbers from largest to smallest in this code block?

Tags: c#

In the printout, numbers will be listed from largest to smallest and the letters will be written next to them.

```
        Console.Write("Enter Sentence : ");
        String sentence = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
        sentence = sentence.ToLower();
        String characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.?,;";
        int[] count = new int[characters.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
        {
            int index = characters.IndexOf(sentence[i]);
            if (index < 0)
                continue;
            else
            {
                count[index]++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < count.Length; i++)
        {
            if (count[i] < 1)
                continue;
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" " + characters[i] + " = " + count[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: If I understand correctly , you want to count the occrences of those characters in the sentence, then print out in order of most common first - is that correct?

Comment: yes it will be like that

Comment: YOu would be better off with a Dictionary<char, int>

Comment: The use of LINQ is not mandatory, it is accepted as such.

Comment: You can write the code with LINQ, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `Dictionary<char, int>` to count the occurence of each char in that sentence. That's the most efficient way. Then you can use a simple one-liner LINQ to order it by count:

```
sentence = sentence.ToLower();
var charCounter = new Dictionary<char, int>(sentence.Length);
foreach(char c in sentence)
{
    charCounter.TryGetValue(c, out int count);
    charCounter[c] = ++count;
}

foreach(var kv in charCounter.OrderByDescending(kv => kv.Value))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key} = {kv.Value}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this and of course thanks to everyone else.

Comment: One-liner, for fun: `sentence.GroupBy(c => c).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).Select(g => new { Letter = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToList().ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine($"Char: {a.Letter} Count: {a.Count}"));`